# Google Apps Script error - Service unavailable: Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, gmail

My Google Apps Script time-based Trigger is failing with error:

> Service unavailable: Gmail (line XXX, file "XXXXXXXXXXXX")

The code gets emails from a Google Sheet and send emails to them.

My spreadsheet has more than 8k+ records.
Initially I suspected error due to data loading, but later I realized that it is not due to load as my friend is able to run the script smoothly without any error from her gmail account.

I have checked my gmail storage limit and freed up.
Cleared browser history and cookies.

Please help this issue resolved and let us know some precautions or steps to prevent this happening in future.

Comment: How often are you executing the trigger? How many emails is it sending per run?

Comment: Your browser isn't the issue, since Google Apps Script does not execute in your browser.

Comment: @AmitAgarwal We have 3 triggers set up on the script and all over maximum of 80 emails are sent.

Comment: we have 3 triggers set up on the script. Interestingly only 1st trigger (set up @3pm-4pm which sends max of 80 emails) is failing where as next 2 triggers (@4pm-5pm sends max of 15-20 emails & 5pm-6pm  sends max of 20-30 emails) are running successfully.

Comment: Same issue here. Hoping it's just a temporary issue.